It does not change the data in database but it shows the new data in developer tools
It does not change the data in the database but it shows the new data in developer tools
It was supposed to change it but it didn't can anybody who uses vue js help been stuck in this problem for quite some time now already tried this, this code shows the newly inputted data but does not change the data in the database
<template>
    <div class="modal fade" id="editRolesModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="editRolesModalLabel" aria-modal="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header bg-soft-success" style="padding: 20px;">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Role</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form @submit.prevent="updateRole">
                        <input type="hidden" v-model="roleId">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="role-name-edit" class="form-label">Role Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="role-name-edit" v-model="roleName" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="description-edit" class="form-label">Description</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description-edit" v-model="description" required>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Update</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
    props: ['selectedRoleId'],

    data() {
        return {
            roleId: '',
            roleName: '',
            description: ''
        };
    },

    watch: {
        selectedRoleId(newVal) {
            if (newVal) {
                this.fetchRole(newVal);
            }
        }
    },

    methods: {
        fetchRole(selectedRoleId) {
            axios.get(`/api/roles/${selectedRoleId}`)
                .then(response => {
                    const roleDetails = response.data;
                    this.roleName = roleDetails.role_name;
                    this.description = roleDetails.description;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error fetching role:', error);
                });
        },

        updateRole() {
            axios.put(`/api/roles/${this.selectedRoleId}`, {
                role_name: this.roleName,
                description: this.description
            })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(`Role with ID ${this.selectedRoleId} updated successfully`, response.data);
                this.$emit('roleUpdated', response.data);
                this.$refs.editRolesModal.hide();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error updating role:', error);
            });
        }
    }
};
</script>


What's in your network devtools on the client side? Can you see the payload going out to the backend?
